# Display numbers in meters of htop

Tags: debian, configuration, htop

My server is running on debian Wheezy and htop 1.0.1 but it does not display any values on the meters bar except the 100.0% value of CPUs.

Is it possible to show always the values of a meter?

This is the current display of htop on my server:
[image: current]

But I want to have the numbers always on my meters like on this screenshot from https://hisham.hm/htop/index.php?page=screenshots:
[image: expected]

My htoprc is located in ~/.config/htop/htoprc and contains the following data:

```
# The parser is also very primitive, and not human-friendly.
fields=0 48 17 18 38 39 40 2 46 47 49 1
sort_key=46
sort_direction=1
hide_threads=0
hide_kernel_threads=1
hide_userland_threads=0
shadow_other_users=0
show_thread_names=0
highlight_base_name=1
highlight_megabytes=1
highlight_threads=0
tree_view=0
header_margin=1
detailed_cpu_time=0
cpu_count_from_zero=0
color_scheme=0
delay=15
left_meters=LeftCPUs2 CPU Memory Swap
left_meter_modes=1 1 1 1
right_meters=RightCPUs2 Tasks LoadAverage Uptime
right_meter_modes=1 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you create a htoprc file, mine is located in ~/config/htop/htoprc, I don't know how it is under Ubuntu, but that should work too.

inside you just have to put:

```
left_meters=AllCPUs Memory Swap 
left_meter_modes=1 1 1
```

That should give you the output you want.

You can also change the number of the color_scheme. Maybe the background is the same color as the numbers.

Comment: It does already contain exactly these two lines with your values. So this does not work.

Comment: Hmm actually you don't have exactly the same lines.
Can you try commenting the 4 last lines and adding those 4 instead ?
`left_meters=AllCPUs Memory Swap
left_meter_modes=1 1 1
right_meters=Tasks LoadAverage Uptime
right_meter_modes=2 2 2`

Also if this doesn't work, are you sure the percentage are not in the same color as your terminal background ? Because I can see the 100% on the CPU number 3.
You can try changing the color_scheme line with another number maybe

Comment: Changing the color scheme is the answer! The numbers had the same color as the background and weren't visible therefor. Can you post this as an answer please? So I can mark this question as solved.

Comment: I've updated my initial answer

Comment: The color scheme was the exact same problem also for me. The most straight forward solution for me was to choose color scheme "Broken Gray" under Setup (F2) > Colors > Broken Gray which is the same as in htoprc `color_scheme=6` (for htop 2.0.1).

Answer (score 9):

The problem for me wasn't in `~/.config/htop/htoprc` but in the color scheme of the terminal.

I had this problem with One Dark theme in Konsole using the default color schema of htop.

There are two solution:

- Change your terminal color schema
- Change htop color schema: `F2 → Colors → [x] Something different that you like!`

I changed and I can see the numbers now.